# Load file with correct encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-8

I'm loading a file with a filepicker and something goes wrong with the encoding. I don't get the right special chars. Here is the code:

```
 StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
 if (file != null)
 {
     var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
     var rdr  = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream());
 }
```

The reading works perfect, but the encoding not. The file comes in as an ansi-csv file. I can give the StreamReader a encoding like this:

```
var rdr  = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

But this also dosn't work and an `System.Text.Encoding.ANSI` encoding dosn't exist. How can I read the file with the correct Encoding and display my special chars?

Comment: It's a file picker in Metro-Apps ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/br207852.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the current ANSI encoding for the system:

```
var rdr = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

If that is not the correct encoding for the file, then you need to know which encoding was used on the computer where the file was created, and get that encoding to decode it. For example:

```
var rdr = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ibm850"));
```

Comment: thx. Encoding.Default is not accessable in metro-apps but GetEncoding is. I just can't figure out which encoding I have to use for Microsoft CSV files. I have tryed Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1, but in both cases the StreamReader is empty. Does anybody know the right Encoding for (German) MS Excel CSV Files?

Comment: @JanHommes: You can try IBM852 (Central European DOS) or Windows-1250 Central European Windows) .

Comment: Well for me Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250") did the trick thanks guys!